# How to exit full screen mode in textedit FORMAT WINDOW mac 10.13.3

Tags: textedit

can't exit full screen in the FORMAT WINDOW for textedit  mac 10.13.3
Have tried restoring default settings.  The top left buttons: red closes window as it should, orange is not active (the regularly orange button is just gray) and green button does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the Escape key. I know in Finder hitting Esc will get you out of full screen mode. But not every app supports Escape as a way to get out of full screen mode so you can try this keyboard stroke:

***"Command+Control+F"* to exit or enter Full Screen Mode.**